# How to filter data from Firebase Database and display it into android recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase database and it has different data. I used an adapter class to send data to Recycler view. Everything is fine and I could display all the content in recycler view. But when I filter the data based on the user Id using equalTo() function nothing is showing in the recycler view.

How can I solve this?

```
final Query itemFilter = mDatabase.child("items").child("userId")
            .equalTo(UId);
itemFilter.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Album item = singleSnapshot.getValue(Album.class);

                albumList.add(item);

                AlbumsAdapter albumsAdapter = new AlbumsAdapter(UploadHistory.this, albumList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(albumsAdapter);
            }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(UploadHistory.this,"NO DATA FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far. Add your code.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to filter your data.

Comment: Added the code... Check updates

Comment: please, show us your firebase schema

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshots) at `mDatabase`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: It has data such as ,
Name, Number, URL, UserId, Date, Flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer!

The problem was in querying data, just change query to

```
final Query itemFilter = mDatabase.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(UId);
```

then got the expected results...